# Bugtracking in GitLab : Custom Field like Affected Version or Product Version?

Tags: gitlab, vtk, itk

How can I create issue filters in GitLab ?

I'm looking for filter parameter Like 'affectedVersion' in Jira or the 'ProductVersion' in Mantis, to see which bugs in an older framework (ITK,VTK) version has been detected and when they have been solved.

Comment: Add your comments on this feature request: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4307

Comment: Currently you have two options:  1. create labels.  2. create milestones.  Milestones are really the same thing as "Affected Versions".

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have two options:

1. create labels.  I prefer this.
2. create milestones.  Milestones are really the same thing as "Affected Versions", under a different name.

I would probably use labels for things like "angular-2-bug", and "php-6-bug", and would use Milestone to directly map to your  "Affected Version" field you were used to from JIRA.

[image: versions and stuff]

Comment: When the milestone is the version where a bug has been detected. What is the name of the version where the bug fix has been released ? In Jira it's "Affected Versions" and "Target Version". In Mantis "Product Version" and "Fix Version".

Comment: I see that now. You could create affects-1.8 labels

Answer (score 0):

ITK has switched to [Jira](https://issues.itk.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa) a few years ago. VTK uses GitLab, and its [milestones](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues?scope=all&state=opened&utf8=%E2%9C%93&milestone_title=7.1.1) are a filter for versions. But it does not go far back, because switch from Mantis to GitLab issue tracker was not long ago.